# VS-2019 program crashes on first floating point instruction on some servers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point, crash, visual-studio-2019

I have a service with code that runs for years.

Now using the VS-2019 16.3.7/8/9 I get a 0xC000001D (The thread tried to execute an invalid instruction.) exceptions on the first floating point arithmetic in the boot phase of the service on some machines.

Installing the same code base compiled with 16.2.4/5 works.

I have a full memory crash dump from one machine. The crash happens on a call to `_dtol3`.

I can see in the assembly code this situation.

```
0149477B 83 3D B4 AC 55 01 06 cmp         dword ptr [__isa_available (0155ACB4h)],6  
01494782 7C 15                jl          _dtol3_default (01494799h)  
01494784 C5 FA 7E C0          vmovq       xmm0,xmm0  
01494788 62 F1 FD 08 7A C0    vcvttpd2qq  xmm0,xmm0  <---- CRASH
```

`__isa_available` has the value 6. On my machine the value is 5. One machine were we can see the crash is a `XEON Silver 4110` running our software virtualized. Same exe runs on a `XEON E5-2620`. The same exe runs on all my client machines in my company without any problem (a mix of old and new Intel machines).

Looking at the called code, I can see that there is a simple difference and division of to double values comparing it to a value greater or equal 1.0.

```
COleDateTime nowClient = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime(),
nowDB = GetCurrentTime();
COleDateTimeSpan diff = nowDB-nowClient;
if (diff.GetTotalMinutes()>=1)  // <----- CRASH
    ...
```

Is there any way to influence the code creation in the VS to avoid the calls to this code? (Any shim, compatibility setting)

Is there any known change in VS-2019 that influences the floating math since VS 16.2.4, that might has influence on my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the 16.3.x update of Visual Studio. Here is a link to the [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/787296/vs2019-163-seems-to-incorrectly-detect-avx512-on-w.html).

Read it carefully, it actually happens on machines that support AVX512, not older CPUs as the initial post describes. This also contains a couple of workarounds to avoid the issue until Microsoft has a fix.

Comment: The version 16.4.0 seems to have the fix, although the release notes don't mention it.

Comment: It is mentioned under the fixed section "Incorrect code generation with Visual Studio 2019 16.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable the generation of 'advanced' instructions for each project in its "Properties" sheet:

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties" from the pop-up menu.
2. Select/Open the "C/C++" tab in the left-hand pane and then select the "Code Generation" item.
3. In the list of properties then presented in the right-hand pane, select "Not Set" for the "Enabled Enhanced Instruction Set" property (or whichever option will give you code that is compatible with your target PCs).

The compiler's use of `vmovq` implies that you have (at least) "Advanced Vector Extensions" enabled; also, I think (not 100% sure) that `vcvttpd2qq` is in the "AVX2" category.

Comment: "Not set" is selected all of my projects including this one.

Comment: @xMRi Hmm. Then it appears to be a problem with the ATL/MFC library you're linking to. Are you using static or dynamic linkage? Have you tried different SDKs?

Comment: I see the problem currently in two projects. One links statically to CRT and MFC. The other uses the DLL version for CRT and MFC... but as I can see in the code is always linked in the EXE modul statically and isn't located in a DLL. The kind of CRT usage (DLL or static linking) does not affect this code.

Comment: The code comes from Loaded msvcrt.lib(ftol3.obj) and is linked statically.

Comment: @xMRi OK, so maybe try using an earlier SDK: Project->Options->General->Platform_SDK_Version and select an earlier one. My VS2019 lists "10.0.18362.0" as the latest and then a few others, starting with "10.0.17763.0;" the update from `17...` to `18...` could well be the problem. If it is, then perhaps worth raising it with the VS support team as a bug. *(Or maybe try linking dynamically: that would only work if the call is made from the ATL library.)*

Comment: The /arch: compiler option sets a minimum instruction set and so does not resolve this issue.